# как получить день из строки

Tags: javascript

есть строка n="08.09.2022" формат день месяц год
эту строку я форматирую под new Date (n)
и хочу получить день (08)
Но при обращении к .getDate получаю 09
как это исправить

```
n="08.09.2022"
x = new Date (x)
day = x.getDate
console.log (day)
```

Comment: преобразуйте в "2022-09-08"

Comment: new Date () - принимает значения  - месяц, день, год. В вашем случае (Tue Aug 09 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)). И поэтому возвращает 9

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```js
const date = '08.09.2022';

const getDay = (str) => {
  const [day, month, year] = str.split('.');
  
  return new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}`).getDate();
}

console.log(getDay(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#parameters) принимает формат `MM/DD/YYYY` или параметрами дату - `YYYY, MM, DD`, вы можете разбить строку по `.` и полученный массив передать в `new Date()`

```js
var n = "08.09.2022";

var x = n.split('.');
x = new Date(+x[2], x[1] - 1, +x[0]);

var day = x.getDate();

console.log(x.toLocaleString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'}));
console.log('day - '+day);
```

`x[1] - 1` - потому что месяц считается с нуля (0 - январь, 11 - декабрь).

---

Или же если строка всегда будет `DD.MM.YYYY`, то можно разбить строку, развернуть массив при помощи `.reverse()`:

```js
var n = "08.09.2022";

var x = n.split('.').reverse();
x = new Date(x);

var day = x.getDate();
console.log(x.toLocaleString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'}));
console.log('day - '+day);
```

Answer (score -1):

можно с помощью регулярного выражения

```
n="08.09.2022"; 
console.log(/([\d]{2})\.([\d]{2})\.([\d]{4})/.exec(n)[1])//день
console.log(/([\d]{2})\.([\d]{2})\.([\d]{4})/.exec(n)[2])//месяц
console.log(/([\d]{2})\.([\d]{2})\.([\d]{4})/.exec(n)[3])//год
```

или проще

```
n="08.09.2022"; 
console.log(n.split(".")[0])//день
```